# Liipimagine Bundle - Images not cached

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, caching, rights, liipimaginebundle

I received a project and I'm trying to start it in  **Docker** with **NGINX** environment. But it seems I have a bug with LiipImagine. The project use Symfony 4 and LIIPImagine version 2.0.x-dev.

A page should display images from cache, exemple of an image URL : 
https://localhost:8443/media/cache/live_feed_message/images/live_feed_message/5c486df1a78fe_lama-750389_960_720.jpg

The directory exists with rights :

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000 4069 Jan 23 13:35 live_feed_message
```

All images are stored in **public/images/live_feed_mesage/** and in **public/media/cache/live_feed_message/images/live_feed_message** the corresponding image doesn't exists.

I figured out that if I use the command from LiipImagine:
**php app/console liip:imagine:cache:resolve relative/path/to/image1.jpg**

It gives this result :

```
http://localhost/media/cache/quizz_thumbnail/images/live_feed_message/name_file.jpg
http://localhost/media/cache/quizz_sponsors_icon/images/live_feed_message/name_file.jpg
http://localhost/media/cache/live_feed_message/images/live_feed_message/name_file.jpg
```

And then the corresponding image exists in cache (public/media/cache/live_feed_message/images/live_feed_message) and the image displays correctly on the page...

In network tab from development console, I checked the response from an HTTP request. And I get this Symfony response:

```
Unable to write to the "/srv/api/public/media/cache/live_feed_message/images/live_feed_message" directory.
```

Does someone know what could be the issue ?

**Since 2 days I can't resolve this issue, so thanks for your help !**

**PS**: I overrided a route from **routing.yaml** from the bundle.
In the path there was /resolve and I overrided with this (in fact I deleted **/resolve** from liip_imagine_filter path):

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"


liip_imagine_filter:
    path:  /media/cache/{filter}/{path}
    defaults:
        _controller: '%liip_imagine.controller.filter_action%'
    methods:
        - GET
    requirements:
        filter: '[A-z0-9_-]*'
        path: .+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maybe try being more permissive with `chmod -R 777 public/images`. In local it's not a very big deal, it's in production that you should fine tune your permissions. That would probably clear out your errors and you could go on coding.

An actual permission for production would be 755 IIRC.

Comment: I searched an issue in the configuration of the bundle but finally I used chmod -R 777 but not on public/images. I used it on public/media/cache folder. Because it tries to write there and not in public/images. I don't know if it's the best practice but it works...

Comment: yes the cache is in /cache but the uploaded images are in /images. The image filters are not stored in the same directory as sources. I think it's good to separate what is uploaded from what is generated